# Order an array while the user inputs the value of each array position

Tags: c

I'm trying to order the values of an array while a user is inputting it's values.

The thing is that I want to avoid trying to use the "bubble" or the "quick sort" method.

Here is my code and how it's working:

```
int i, j, k;
      int number;
      for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) {
          printf("Give me the number #%d to add to the list: ", i + 1);
          while (!scanf("%d", &list[i])) {
            while(getchar() != '\n');
            printf("You can't use chars!.\n");
            printf("Give me the number #%d to add to the list: ", i + 1);
          }
          number = list[i];
          if (number < list[i-1]) {
            list[i-1] = list[i];
            list[i] = number;
          }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1) {
        printf("%d,", list[i]);
      }
```

what am I getting:

```
How much numbers do you want to order? 5
Give me the number #1 to add to the list: 5
Give me the number #2 to add to the list: 4
Give me the number #3 to add to the list: 3
Give me the number #4 to add to the list: 2
Give me the number #5 to add to the list: 1
4,3,2,1,1,% // here is the problem, the expected output should be: 1,2,3,4,5 (for example, if I have 5,8,3,2,9 I should get: 2,3,5,8,9).
```

I would appreciate an explanation about why my code is not working and if possible a recommendation on how to visualize problems like this one in the future.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your algorithm is incorrect. If it was, sorting  would be O(n)! Just try to see what happen if 5,4,3 is entered: a/list={5} b/ list={4,5} c/ list={4,3,5}

Comment: @AlainMerigot did not understand your answer?

Comment: Do you want the list to be always sorted as numbers are inserted? Or do you just want them to come as sorted when you need it?

Comment: @Taegyung I want to order them automatically while the user inputs each number. For example, the user inputs 2, so `list[0] = 2` then the user inputs 1, so `list[0] = 1` and `list[1] = 2`.

Comment: Then I think Insertion sort is your friend, which you are doing, incorrectly...

Comment: @Taegyung can you help me explaining with an example? please.

Comment: Better yet would be some sort of tree structure, e.g. a binary tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the array sorted, you should do a (partial) insertion sort for every input number.

Just reminding you of the algorithm of insertion sort, it does the following for the i-th iteration:

1. The array is sorted from index 0 to index i-1
2. And you have a new number, list[i].
3. You should determine where this new number fits in the array, so you shift numbers to the back until you see where the new number fits.
4. Once you see a number that's not bigger than the new one, now you can fit the new one right after that number.

The problem with your code is that you don't shift correctly.

You have to shift **all** numbers that are greater than the new number to the back to make space for the new one. But your code only shifts the last number.

```c
    int i, j, k;
    int number;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("Give me the number #%d to add to the list: ", i + 1);
        while (!scanf("%d", &list[i]))
        {
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                ;
            printf("You can't use chars!.\n");
            printf("Give me the number #%d to add to the list: ", i + 1);
        }
        number = list[i];

        /* Here's the point! Shift all numbers bigger than *number* to the back. */
        for (j = i; j > 0 && number < list[j - 1]; j--)
        {
            list[j] = list[j - 1];
        }
        list[j] = number;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i = i + 1)
    {
        printf("%d,", list[i]);
    }
```

(Excuse the re-formatting, that's just a thing my IDE does.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate the explanation and the sample code! Going to study this more deeply.

Comment: How is it possible to make the opposite thing with the edit you provided?

Comment: What you do mean "the opposite?" If you mean sorting in descending order, change the direction of the comparing operator. `number > list[j-1]`.

Comment: Yes, but when I do that: `for (j = i; j > 0 && number > list[j - 1]; j = j - 1)` I'm getting: `Your ordered list is: 5,32766,32766,32766,32766,%`.

Comment: What was your input? I can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5 was my input.

Comment: Maybe it's problem outside the code in question? Like how you declared/intialized `size` and `list`. I don't see any problem: https://ideone.com/jbpDbx

Comment: Got it, I changed something more. I'm sorry for the confusion, Thank you very much for the help, @Taegyung .

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid bubble sort or insertion sort, you can simply call a merge sort after each input. That would make your entire program O(x * nlogn), where n log n is the run time of your merge sort and x is the runtime of your input loop.

The problem with your current implementation is that it does not correctly order the remaining elements. Imagine the following:

```
user inputs 2 --> array now has = [2]
user inputs 7 --> array now has = [2, 7] 
user inputs 3 --> array now has = [2, 3, 7]
```

Do you see how this array puts 3 right in the middle of 2 and 7? Which means the sorting must also move all elements, shifted to the right.

Your current implementation does not do this. Instead, your implementation shifts elements from the left, to the right just once.

Even worse, your implementation is bounded by your input loop. Which means that you are only sorting the array, within a very specific local range, that is bounded by your input loop. Instead of sorting the array, within the arrays actual range.

What happens if a user inputs the following numbers: 2, 7, 4, 1? Your loop is out of the first index, so the 1 is only being compared to values 7 and 4.

Comment: Any sample code with explanation? I would really appreciate it.